# Not able to click on a flash object

Tags: javascript, selenium, flash, selenium-webdriver

How to click flash object inside a frame. HTML code is given below.

I found many related topics but none of them resolved my issue. So I am posting my HTML code here. I am new to selenium so please bear with me.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Visualizer Plugin</title>
  <link href="../../plugins/Visualizer/resources/css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="../../plugins/Visualizer/resources/javascript/flex.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script src="../../plugins/Visualizer/resources/javascript/PluginSupport.js?server=blt05574004" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script src="../../plugins/Visualizer/resources/javascript/BaseController.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script src="../../plugins/Visualizer/resources/javascript/Setup.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      overflow: hidden
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body scroll="no" style="background-color: transparent;" onload="initSetupScript();">
  <div align="center">
    <div id="flashcontent">
      <object width="100%" height="100%" id="Visualizer" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000">
   <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
   <param name="align" value="middle">
   <param name="quality" value="high">
   <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
   <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain">
   <param name="type" value="application/x-shockwave-flash">
   <param name="src" value="../../plugins/Visualizer/resources/swf/../../plugins/Visualizer/resources/swf/Visualizer.swf?r=7.5.00">
   <param name="flashvars" value="bridgeName=Visualizer">
  </object>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    var src = "../../plugins/Visualizer/resources/swf/Visualizer";
    var id = "Visualizer";
    var uri = "../../plugins/Visualizer/resources/swf/";
    var flashvars = "";
    var release = "7.5.00";
    createSWF(src, id, uri, release, flashvars);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: udpated my answer

Answer (score 1):

So you need `flashcontent` it not `flash` exactly. You can use below XPATH

```
//div[@id='flashcontent']//param[@name='quality']
```

Above xpath will return the value as `quality` element

Note : If above element is comes under any frame then you need to switch it first

If Selenium can't operate on Flash content. You need to use another framework for automating the Flash content like : [**Sikuli**](http://www.sikuli.org/)

Refer :

http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/sikuli-tutorial-part-1/

http://www.sikuli.org/testimonials.html

Hope it will help you.